# How replace text and endline in multiple file in powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell

i have multiple files like this

```
TEST:200333
75252
TEST:198234
201756
TEST:201616
274
TEST:200118
934521
TEST:123456
1234
```

and I want an output like this

```
200333;75252
198234;201756
201616;274
200118;934521
123456;1234
```

I tried this code but it doesn't work:
`powershell -Command "(gc myFile.txt) -replace 'TEST:(\.+)\r\n(\.+)\r', '\1;\2' | Out-File -encoding ASCII mynewFile.txt"`

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running? You mentioned that the `-Raw` parameter threw an error in the posted solution? `-Raw` was introduced in PowerShell version 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A no-regex approach that just concatenates every other line:

```
powershell -Command "gc myFile.txt | % {$i=0}{if($i++%2){"$prev;$_"}else{$prev=$_.Substring(5)}} | sc mynewFile.txt -enc ASCII"
```

Less code-golfy version:

```
Get-Content myFile.txt | ForEach-Object -Begin {$i = 0} {
    if ($i++ % 2 -ne 0) {         # odd line
        "$prev;$_"                #   output "value from previous line;current line"
    } else {                      # even line
        $prev = $_.Substring(5)   #   remember value, cut off the "TEST:"
    }
} | Set-Content mynewFile.txt -Encoding ASCII
```

Comment: @Flavio That's good to hear! Take-away: It pays to stop and think if an approach without regex would also work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
powershell -Command "(gc myFile.txt -Raw) -replace '(?m)^TEST:(\d+)\r?\n(\d+)\r?$', '$1;$2' | Out-File -encoding ASCII mynewFile.txt"
```

Or,

```
powershell -Command "[system.io.file]::ReadAllText('myFile.txt')  -replace '(?m)^TEST:(\d+)\r?\n(\d+)\r?$', '$1;$2' | Out-File -encoding ASCII mynewFile.txt"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5ETEST%3A%28%5Cd%2B%29%5Cr%3F%5Cn%28%5Cd%2B%29%5Cr%3F%24&i=TEST%3A200333%0D%0A75252%0D%0ATEST%3A198234%0D%0A201756%0D%0ATEST%3A201616%0D%0A274%0D%0ATEST%3A200118%0D%0A934521%0D%0ATEST%3A123456%0D%0A1234&r=%241%3B%242). Note the use of `-Raw` option that slurps the whole file into a single string.

[image]

The regex matches

- `(?m)` - multiline mode on
- `^` - line start
- `TEST:` - some fixed text
- `(\d+)` -  Group 1: one or more digits
- `\r?\n` - a CRLF (carriage return + line feed)/LF (line feed) line ending
- `(\d+)` -  Group 2: one or more digits
- `\r?` - an optional CR (carriage return)
- `$` - end of a line.

Comment: I obtain this errorTermine 'TEST:200333' non riconosciuto come nome di cmdlet, funzione, programma eseguibile o file script. Controllare l
'ortografia del nome o verificare che il percorso sia incluso e corretto, quindi riprovare.
In riga:1 car:12
+ TEST:200333 <<<<  75252 TEST:198234 201756 TEST:201616 274 TEST:200118 934521 TEST:123456 1234 -replace (?m)^SMPP:(\d
+)\r?\n(\d+)\r?$ $1;$2
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (TEST:200333:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @Flavio Please use the full command I have just updated. It works on my end.

Comment: I obtain an error with the -RAW parameter. If I remove it, it doesn't give me an error but it still doesn't work, the output file is the same as the input file. If I don't use the regex but just fixed text it works. Any suggestions?

Comment: powershell -Command "(gc myFile.txt -Raw) -replace '(?m)^TEST:(\d+)\r?\n
(\d+)\r?$', '$1;$2' | Out-File -encoding ASCII mynewFile.txt"
Get-Content : Impossibile trovare un parametro corrispondente al nome 'Raw'.
In riga:1 car:33
+ (gc VacciniSUM_20210510.txt -Raw <<<< ) -replace '(?m)^TEST:(\d+)\r?\n(\d+)\r?$', ';' | Out-File -encoding ASCII myne
wFile.txt
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Comment: @Flavio If you are using some old PS version, try the second command with `[system.io.file]::ReadAllText`.

Comment: now I obtain a file with only separator
;
;
;
;
;

Comment: @Flavio If you need more help, please share your sample file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232573/discussion-between-flavio-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: I was able to do it with the Tomalak answer. Don't know why your code doesn't work in my machine, really thank you for your support